# Emploi métaphorique du mot « parthénogenèse »

Tags: sens, usage, science, physique

> En Physique, il n'y a pas de *parthénogenèse*. Même Newton s'est appuyé sur
>   ses précédents.

Peut-on employer métaphoriquement le mot *parthénogenèse* (ou bien *naissance vierge*) dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je ne pense pas que la métaphore soit facilement comprise. Ce serait plutôt ici *génération spontanée* mais j'écrirais plutôt :

> En physique, les nouveaux concepts ne sortent pas de nulle part. Même Newton s'est appuyé sur les théories antérieures.

Comment: On peut utiliser naissance vierge ? Ça sera compris ?

Comment: Non, *naissance vierge* n'a pas beaucoup de sens en français.

Comment: Oui! +1 pour la *génération spontanée*. En contexte scientifique informel, j'entendais parfois aussi *ex-nihilo*

Comment: Il n'y a pas de terme français qui couvre tout le sens de ce terme scientifique, ni même dans ce contexte. Ici on veut dire que tout concept scientifique est issu d'au moins deux autres et non pas évolué d’un seul (puisque la parthénogenèse est une reproduction monoparentale dont le fruit est un clone de la mère).